# Swapping axis of descending bars in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array of positive integers like this:

```
inp = np.array([8,2,7,6,1,6,1,4,8,2,1,6,5])
```

I want to make a new `numpy` array `[f(1), f(2), f(3),...]` where `f(n)` calculates how many values of `inp` does not exceed `n`. Zero values of `f(n)` are ignored. In this specific case my expected output is:

```
out = np.array([13,10,8,8,7,6,3,2])
```

I have tried looping:

```
[len(inp[inp>=i]) for i in range(1, max(inp)+1)]
```

but this is not efficient. How can I do this using `numpy` methods?

Comment: Do you have a working loop based solution?

Comment: Show your loop. I don't understand how you got the output you show for the given input.

Comment: I'll add it soon.

Comment: you're right, I made same flaws. Now it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you can just use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
In [17]: len(inp)-np.bincount(inp).cumsum()[:-1]
Out[17]: array([13, 10,  8,  8,  7,  6,  3,  2])
```